# Chunked calculation of mean temperatures of multiple dask/xarray datasets

Tags: python, dask, netcdf, python-xarray, chunks

I have 2 folders of MIN and MAX temperatures netCDF files.

I am trying to calculate mean temperatures between them.

Initially I used `numpy.mean()` for calculation, but since it was eating my RAM, I decided to calculate means with `dask` chunks

```
import dask
import xarry


DS_MIN = xarray.open_mfdataset(MIN_TEMPS_FILES, chunks={'time': 10}, concat_dim='time', combine='by_coords').temp
DS_MAX = xarray.open_mfdataset(MAX_TEMPS_FILES, chunks={'time': 10}, concat_dim='time', combine='by_coords').temp
DS_MEAN = dask.array.from_array([DS_MIN, DS_MAX], chunks={'time': 10}).mean(axis=0)
```

But unfortunately with same result. RAM is fully occupied by calculations.

I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```py
DS_MIN = xarray.open_mfdataset(MIN_TEMPS_FILES, chunks={'time': 10}, concat_dim='time', combine='by_coords').temp
DS_MAX = xarray.open_mfdataset(MAX_TEMPS_FILES, chunks={'time': 10}, concat_dim='time', combine='by_coords').temp

# I don't see a reason to call Dask on these things again, they're already dask-y
# DS_MEAN = dask.array.from_array([DS_MIN, DS_MAX], chunks={'time': 10}).mean(axis=0)

dask.compute(DS_MIN.mean(axis=0), DS_MAX.mean(axis=0))
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I need to compute mean between those ds_min ds_max datasets. They contain same size, shape, same coordinates and same timerange data, only different temperatures. As I understand, your suggestion will compute means of each dataset not between them. And another question, should I stick with chunks="auto" or manual values?

Comment: Maybe you want to add them together and then divide by two?  Maybe you want to concatenate/stack the datasets and then compute the mean along some axis?

Comment: Yes I want to add them and divide by two

Comment: as appeared da.from_array() eats up whole memory. I don't understand how to force dask to make chunked calculations of two datasets. Seems that dask just keeps adding everythin in the memory